# Futures.awaitAll replacement in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, fork-join

I need to spawn set of Futures and wait untill all of them complete either with failure or with some success.

The recent Scala 2.10 doesn't contain anything like that or I did miss something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Future.sequence` to turn many independent `Future`s into one that will not complete until all those constituents complete.

Comment: `Await.result(Future.sequence(fts), timeout.millis)` is significantly different from `Futures.awaitAll(timeout, fts: _*)`, though, right? Because if one of the futures times out, you don't have a way to get the results of the futures that completed.